# Unable to access values assigned in linked list in python

Tags: python

I was given an assignment to delete the elements in a linked list whose sum is 0. I have tried this code. But I get an error like 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'"

```
import random
class Node :
    def __init__( self, data ) :
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
    def givedata(self):
        return self.data    

class LinkedList :
    def __init__( self ) :
        self.head = None        

    def add( self, data ) :
        node = Node( data )
        if self.head == None :  
            self.head = node
        else :
            node.next = self.head
            node.next.prev = node                       
            self.head = node            

    def search( self, k ) :
        p = self.head
        if p != None :
            while p.next != None :
                if ( p.data == k ) :
                    return p                
                p = p.next
            if ( p.data == k ) :
                return p
        return None

    def remove( self, p ) :
        tmp = p.prev
        p.prev.next = p.next
        p.prev = tmp

    def list_print(self):
        node = self.head 
        while node:
            print (node.data,end=" ")
            node = node.next

    def getdata(self):
        self.nodedata=self.head
        return self.nodedata.data
```

script:

```
ll=LinkedList()
for i in range(random.randint(2,10)):
    ll.add(random.randint(-50,50))  
ll.list_print()
print('\n')
l1=LinkedList()
while ll:
  while l1:
     if l1.getdata()+ll.getdata()==0:
            print("0\n")#just to know if this works or not
        l1=l1.head.next
   ll=ll.head.next
```

I tried to access data in the linked list of a particular element.
Will you please help me in traversing through linked list

Comment: Please correct the indentation of the last two lines, they are confusing and fail with an indentation error.  Who thought it was a good idea to have variables called `l1` and `ll`?

Comment: Okay the indentation is not good while I was asking the question.

Comment: a small correction l1=ll

Comment: Your correction done in the question as well? You're not doing anything with the value `i` in your code so replace `for i in range(random.randint(2,10)):` with `for i in range(0,8):`. And finish the tour ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to omit some but you cannot choose to add further attributes beyond those defined.

This error is simply saying that the attribute data-width cannot be used where you used it.

Comment: Try to change your variables l1 and l1

Comment: yet the problem persisted

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because

```
l1=LinkedList()
```

creates a new linked list named l1 and you have not added any element to it, it is an empty linked list whose head is None.

When you call

```
l1.getdata()
```

you see that error

**Edit**

```
ll=LinkedList()
for i in range(random.randint(2,10)):
    ll.add(random.randint(-50,50))  
ll.list_print()
print('\n')
ptr1 = ll.head
while ptr1:
  ptr2 = ptr1.next
  while ptr2:
     if ptr1.data+ptr2.data == 0:
            print("0\n")#just to know if this works or not
        ptr2 = ptr2.next
   ptr1 = ptr1.next
```

This code should do what you want

Comment: I forgot to write l1=ll while asking the question. Still then It didn't find me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you create `l1 = LinkedList()`, the `.head` is initialized to `None`.  This causes a problem when you call `.getdata()`, since that method is trying to call `self.head.data`, which is equivalent to calling `None.data`.

You can fix the `.getdata` method using:

```
def getdata(self):
    self.nodedata=self.head
    if not self.nodedata:
        return 0
    return self.nodedata.data
```

Comment: is the way i am traversing trough the elements correct?

Comment: I am not sure; I don't have an understanding of linked lists